# How to get return value from AppleScript in Python?

Tags: python, applescript, appkit

I need to get size of the window in Python and assign it to the variable. I'm trying with this:

```
windowSize = '''
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "%(app)s"
    get size of window 1
    end tell
    ''' % {'app': app} // app = "Terminal


(wSize, error) = Popen(['osascript', '/Setup.scpt'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()
print("Window size is: " + wSize)
```

I get this error only: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`

I'm completely new to Python so I hope you can help me with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pass your AppleScript (i.e. `windowSize`) as input to [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=communicate#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

**Example:**

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

app = "Terminal"

windowSize = '''
    tell application "%(app)s"
      get size of window 1
    end tell
  ''' % {'app': app}

proc = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
wSize, error = proc.communicate(windowSize)
print("Window size is: " + wSize)
```

---

**Notes**:

- In your `windowSize` AppleScript it shouldn't be necessary to `tell application "System Events" to tell ...` - you can just `tell application "%(app)s"` instead. However, you're AppleScript still works assuming *Access for assistive devices is enabled* in System Preferences.
- This will log something like the following to the console:

  > `Window size is: 487, 338`

  You may want to consider utilizing [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) in your `print` statement to replace the comma (`,`) with an `x`. For instance, changing `print` statement in the gist above to this:

  ```py
  print("Window size is: " + wSize.replace(",", " x"))
  ```

  will print something like this instead:

  > `Window size is: 487 x 338`
- If you wanted to replace the two lines of code in the gist above which begin with `proc` and `wSize`) with one line (similar to your OP) then replace them with the following instead:

  ```py
  (wSize, error) = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate(windowSize)
  ```
- To get the windows *width* and *height* as two separate variables you could subsequently utilize the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method to split the `wSize` variable (using the string `", "` as the delimiter). For instance:

  ```py
  # ...
  wWidth = wSize.split(", ")[0]
  wHeight = wSize.split(", ")[1]

  print("Window width is: " + wWidth)
  print("Window height is: " + wHeight)
  ```